# Flutter : TableOverflow not fixed with SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, overflow, singlechildscrollview

I'm working on a problem which I'm not able to fix. I want to have a table with a lot of rows, positioned and centered at the top of the page. Additionally, there's an image button at the left bottom with a fixed distance of 20 to the bottom and the left and a fixed min distance to the table of 20. The table has to be scrollable if it exceeds the available space.
My tree looks as follows :

```
 - Scaffold
 -     Column
 -         SingleChildScrollView
 -             Center
 -                 Table
 -                     TableRows
 -                     :
 -         Align
 -             Padding
 -                 InkWell
```

When I increase the padding of the InkWell then an overflow error is shown. Why doesn't  the SingleChildScrollView do the job ? I always thought that this Widget ovoids the overflow

Comment: You'll need to wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. The overflow error is gone now, but the InkWell Image is not positioned at the end of the screen. there is space left now. I set mainAxisAlignment of Column widget to spaceBetween so I thougt that would be spreaded now to the end. but is is not

Comment: It's inside a nested TabView. That does not work. It works on a blank page

Comment: Please share the full code so that I could help